# Receiving java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.usb.UsbPermissionActivity}

Tags: java, android

Receiving java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity

```
{com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.usb.UsbPermissionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is my log cat:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.usb.UsbPermissionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3499)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3517)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:141)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.android.systemui.usb.UsbPermissionActivity.onDestroy(UsbPermissionActivity.java:148)
     at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5302)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1117)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3486)
```

My Code After onClickListener:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                String User_Name;
                User_Name=username.getText().toString();
                Device_Found=0;
                if(User_Name.toLowerCase().equals("medequip") && password.getText().toString().equals("medequip"))
                {
                    Communication_Ok=0; Permission_Error=0;
                    checkdeviceconnection();
                    if(Device_Found==1)
                    {
                        Data_Rx_Index=Data_Index=setTotal_Frame_Received(0);
                        if(Permission_Error==1)
                        checkdeviceconnection();
                        Receive.start();
                        long i,j;
                        for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
                        for(j=0;j<1000;j++);
                        if(Communication_Ok==1)
                            Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Communication_Ok", 10000).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Communication Failure", 10000).show();
                            Intent i3 = new Intent(Medequiplogin.this,Modes.class);
                            startActivity(i3);
                    }
                  else  
                  {   Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Device Connection Problem", 10000).show();        
                    return;}
                }

                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Plesae Enter valid Username and Password", 10000).show();
                }

            }

        });
        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                username.setText("");
                password.setText("");

            }
        }); 
    }



    protected void checkdeviceconnection() 
    {
        int i,j;
        String as[];
        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        i = deviceList.size();
        if(i==0)
        {
             return;
        }
        as = new String[i];
        deviceList.keySet().toArray(as);

        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            Device_Detials = (UsbDevice)deviceList.get(as[j]);
            if((Device_Detials.getVendorId()==targetVendorID) && (Device_Detials.getProductId()==targetProductID))
            {
                    break;
            }

        }


        if(Device_Detials!=null)
        {
        usbManager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
            if(usbManager.hasPermission(Device_Detials)==true)
            {
            //  Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                Device_Settings(Device_Detials,j);
            }
            else
            {
                //PendingIntent  intent = null;
          //    Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "No Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                usbManager.requestPermission(Device_Detials, null); 
                Permission_Error=1;

                return;         
            }
        Device_Settings(Device_Detials,j);


        }       
    }   

UsbDeviceConnection Device_Settings(UsbDevice device,int Port_No)
{
    UsbEndpoint tOut = null;
    UsbEndpoint tIn = null;
    UsbInterface usbinterface = device.getInterface(Port_No);

    if (usbinterface == null) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Device Found But UnKnown Exception-1", 50000).show();  
        return null;
    }
    int tEndpointCnt = usbinterface.getEndpointCount();
    if (tEndpointCnt >= 2)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < tEndpointCnt; j++)
        {
            if (usbinterface.getEndpoint(j).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK)
                {
                    if (usbinterface.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) 
                    {
                        tOut = usbinterface.getEndpoint(j);
                    }   
                    else if (usbinterface.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN)
                    {
                        tIn = usbinterface.getEndpoint(j);
                    }
                }
        }   
        if (tOut != null && tIn != null) 
        {
            usbInterfaceFound = usbinterface;   
            endpointOut = tOut;         
            endpointIn = tIn;
            deviceFound = device;
            if (device != null) 

            {

                Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, device+" ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                UsbDeviceConnection connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                if (connection != null && connection.claimInterface(usbInterfaceFound, true)) 
                {

                    connection.controlTransfer(0x21, 34, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);
                    connection.controlTransfer(0x21, 32, 0, 0, new byte[] { (byte) 0x80, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08 }, 7, 0);
                    usbDeviceConnection = connection;
                    usbDeviceConnection_For_Transfer = connection;
                    Communication_Byte[0]='&';
                    usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(endpointOut,Communication_Byte, 1, 0);
                    Device_Found=1;
                    return usbDeviceConnection;

                }

                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Device Found But Unable to Open Device(Exception-3)", 50000).show();
                    usbDeviceConnection = null;
                }

        }
    }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Device Found But No End Points(Exception-4)", 50000).show();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Device Found But No End Points(Exception-2)", 50000).show();  
        return null;

    }
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void Manual_Mode(int Total_Size) {

    int i,j,k;
    Communication_Ok=0; 
    Data_Rx_Index=Data_Index=setTotal_Frame_Received(0);
//  Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, usbDeviceConnection_For_Transfer+"", 50000).show(); 
    Mode_Selection=0;
    if(usbDeviceConnection_For_Transfer==null)
    i=0;
    else
    i=0;
    byte []dataRx_2= new byte[1];
    Communication_Error=0;
    for(k=0;k<5;k++)
    {   
        dataRx_2[0]='&';
        usbDeviceConnection_For_Transfer.bulkTransfer(endpointOut, dataRx_2, 1, 0);
        for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
            for(j=0;j<1000;j++);
        if(Communication_Ok==1)
        {

            byte []dataRx_1= new byte[Total_Size+4];
            dataRx_1[0]='*';  
            dataRx_1[Total_Size+4-1]='#'; 
            if(mm.Present_Test_IS_OR_IR==1)      //IR
            {
                dataRx_1[1]=(byte)0xA4;   //for manual mode
                dataRx_1[2]=(byte)0xA4;   //for manual mode
            }
            else  //IS
            {
                dataRx_1[1]=(byte)0xA5;   //for manual mode
                dataRx_1[2]=(byte)0xA5;   //for manual mode
            }
            for(i=0;i<Total_Size;i++)
            {
                dataRx_1[i+3]=(byte)((mm.Checked_Buttons[(int) i])+0x30);
            }
            usbDeviceConnection_For_Transfer.bulkTransfer(endpointOut, dataRx_1, Total_Size+4, 0);
            break;
        }       
    }
    if(k>=4)
    Communication_Error=1;      
}
public static int getTotal_Frame_Received() 
        {
            return Total_Frame_Received;
        }

public static int setTotal_Frame_Received(int total_Frame_Received)
        {
            Total_Frame_Received = total_Frame_Received;
            return total_Frame_Received;
        }
Thread Receive  = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);   
        UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
        int i,j;
        byte [] datarx=new byte[1]; 
        while (true) 
        {
            request.initialize(usbDeviceConnection, endpointIn);
            request.queue(buffer, 100);
            if (usbDeviceConnection.requestWait() == request) 
            {
                if(Data_Rx_Index==0)  
                Data_Index=0;
                for(i=0;i<100;i++)
                {
                    Data_Recevied_From_MC [i]= buffer.get(i);
                    Data_Index=i;
                    if(Data_Recevied_From_MC [i]=='#')
                    break;
                }
                byte [] Data_Recevied_From_MC_1=new byte [i-1]; 
                if(Data_Recevied_From_MC [0]=='&')
                {
                    Communication_Ok=1;Data_Rx_Index=0; 

                }
                if(Data_Recevied_From_MC [0]=='*' && Data_Recevied_From_MC [Data_Index]=='#' && Mode_Selection==1)
                {
                    Data_Recevied_From_MC_1[0]=Data_Recevied_From_MC[1];
                    Data_Recevied_From_MC_1[1]=Data_Recevied_From_MC[2];
                    Data_Recevied_From_MC_1[2]=Data_Recevied_From_MC[3];
                    Data_Recevied_From_MC_1[3]=Data_Recevied_From_MC[4];
                    /*for(j=0;j<i;j++)
                    {
                        if(Data_Recevied_From_MC[j+2]!='#')
                            Data_Recevied_From_MC_1[j]= (Data_Recevied_From_MC[j+2]);
                        else
                            break;  
                    } */
                    ByteBuffer buffer_1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(Data_Recevied_From_MC_1);
                    Resistance=buffer_1.getFloat();
                    setTotal_Frame_Received(1);
                }
                else if(Data_Recevied_From_MC [0]=='*' && Data_Recevied_From_MC [Data_Index]=='#')
                {

                    Test_Point_No=(int)Data_Recevied_From_MC[1]; 
                    if(mm.Present_Test_IS_OR_IR==1)
                    {   
                        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
                        {
                            if(Data_Recevied_From_MC[j+2]!='#')
                                Data_Recevied_From_MC_1[j]= (Data_Recevied_From_MC[j+2]);
                            else
                                break;  
                        }
                        ByteBuffer buffer_1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(Data_Recevied_From_MC_1);
                        Resistance=buffer_1.getFloat();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Current=(int)Data_Recevied_From_MC[2];
                    }
                    setTotal_Frame_Received(1);
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                    }});
                }
        else 
            {
            Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "No data received", 50000).show();   
            break;
            }

       }

    }
    });
```

When I was Start Debugging i got strucked on line 172 i.e at permission_error=1...after line 172 showing UNFORTUNATELY SYSTEM UI STOPPED in android Screen
Here's my code:

```
   protected void checkdeviceconnection() 
        {
            int i,j;
            String as[];
            UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
            HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
            i = deviceList.size();
            if(i==0)
            {
                 return;
            }
            as = new String[i];
            deviceList.keySet().toArray(as);

            for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                Device_Detials = (UsbDevice)deviceList.get(as[j]);
                if((Device_Detials.getVendorId()==targetVendorID) && (Device_Detials.getProductId()==targetProductID))
                {
                        break;
                }

            }


            if(Device_Detials!=null)
            {
            usbManager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
                if(usbManager.hasPermission(Device_Detials)==true)
                {
                //  Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    Device_Settings(Device_Detials,j);
                }
                else
                {
                    //PendingIntent  intent = null;
              //    Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "No Permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    usbManager.requestPermission(Device_Detials, null); 
                    Permission_Error=1;

                    return;         
                }
            Device_Settings(Device_Detials,j);


            }       
        }
UsbDeviceConnection Device_Settings(UsbDevice device,int Port_No)
{
    UsbEndpoint tOut = null;
    UsbEndpoint tIn = null;
    UsbInterface usbinterface = device.getInterface(Port_No);

    if (usbinterface == null) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Device Found But UnKnown Exception-1", 50000).show();  
        return null;
    }
    int tEndpointCnt = usbinterface.getEndpointCount();
    if (tEndpointCnt >= 2)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < tEndpointCnt; j++)
        {
            if (usbinterface.getEndpoint(j).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK)
                {
                    if (usbinterface.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) 
                    {
                        tOut = usbinterface.getEndpoint(j);
                    }   
                    else if (usbinterface.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN)
                    {
                        tIn = usbinterface.getEndpoint(j);
                    }
                }
        }   
        if (tOut != null && tIn != null) 
        {
            usbInterfaceFound = usbinterface;   
            endpointOut = tOut;         
            endpointIn = tIn;
            deviceFound = device;
            if (device != null) 

            {

                Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, device+" ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                UsbDeviceConnection connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                if (connection != null && connection.claimInterface(usbInterfaceFound, true)) 
                {

                    connection.controlTransfer(0x21, 34, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);
                    connection.controlTransfer(0x21, 32, 0, 0, new byte[] { (byte) 0x80, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08 }, 7, 0);
                    usbDeviceConnection = connection;
                    usbDeviceConnection_For_Transfer = connection;
                    Communication_Byte[0]='&';
                    usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(endpointOut,Communication_Byte, 1, 0);
                    Device_Found=1;
                    return usbDeviceConnection;

                }

                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Device Found But Unable to Open Device(Exception-3)", 50000).show();
                    usbDeviceConnection = null;
                }

        }
    }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Device Found But No End Points(Exception-4)", 50000).show();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(Medequiplogin.this, "Device Found But No End Points(Exception-2)", 50000).show();  
        return null;

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Show related code. What's line UsbPermissionActivity.java:148?

Comment: Can you show that line? Its throwing Null pointer exception.

Comment: I posted my code above..after onClickListener

Comment: Check what's null. Have you initialized username?

Comment: Yup..i was initialized username and password...

Comment: Can you please tell what's line number 148?

Comment: What is at UsbPermissionActivity.java:148 ?

Comment: Post `onDestroy()` method of  `UsbPermissionActivity.java`

Comment: Checking for Connected USB DEVICES..and to check for target vendor ID and Target product Id

Comment: Can u help me with the code please @SilentKiller

Comment: @Lakshmansundeep you need to post your onDestroy() method of `UsbPermissionActivity`

Comment: Actually i took the usb permission in manifest file...and where should i call onDestroy() of UsbpermissionActivity explain me with the code please...@SilentKiller

Comment: You don't need to call onDestroy method. It will be called internally. Its activity lifecycle method. Show its code as that is causing exception.

Comment: @Lakshmansundeep is it 10 mark question ? *explain me with the code please*

Comment: @SilentKiller 15 marks :P

Comment: Nope 25 marks question....;):p

Comment: If you can't help *us* in helping *you*, we can't do anything. happy coding

Comment: Ok chill...@MysticMagic debugging my code @ 148th line sending you my code

Comment: My code was posted Above after Debugging @MysticMagic

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem. It was happening on Android 4.4.2 but worked fine on 5.0. I was able to solve it by following the examples here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

Specifically, I had to move the registerReceiver to onCreate() instead of onStart().

You should try to simplify your code down to a smaller test case that follows the documented pattern on the usb host page.